# Cordova contacts not coming up

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

**Problem**

I'm trying to fetch contacts from any iOS device using Cordova as am developing an app using phonegap. I have included the **ViewContacts.h** and **ViewContacts.m** files in xCode 5.0. Also installed the cordova plugin for contacts and have mentioned **`<plugin name="Contacts" value="CDVContacts" />`** in **config.xml** but still when I try to get contacts I don't get any error or contacts. After **`new ContactFindOptions();`** function gets called it doesn't do anything. Any guidance or suggestions will be great. I'm struggling with this problem from last 2 days.

The below javascript code works fine in Android.

**Code**

```
function searchContact()
{
    alert("Hello........");
    // specify contact search criteria
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    alert("Before");// <-This ALERT

    options.filter      =   "";                 // empty search string returns all contacts
    options.multiple    =   true;               // return multiple results
    filter              =   ["displayName", "phoneNumbers", "emails"];  // return contact.displayName field

    // find contacts
    navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);
    alert("After");
}//List all contacts
```

Comment: @rmaddy do you know anything in regards to my prob ?

Comment: No. I was just cleaning up the tags. I have no experience with Cordova.

Comment: ok, why did you removed Phonegap ?

Comment: I didn't. I only removed the xcode tag (which I removed again). You didn't add the phonegap tag initially. And read the description for the xcode tag. It doesn't apply to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Very late answer, but it may help somebody else. There's no such thing as "displayname" on iOS. You should look for the name object.

```
    filter              =   ["name", "phoneNumbers", "emails"];
```

And on the success function, you should look for the first name and last name like this :

```
var firstName = contacts[i].name.givenName;
var lastName = contacts[i].name.familyName;
```